# change the style of text like color,textstyle,size,etc... programatically by changing style file

Tags: android

i have made one style file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

into the res/value. currently the text color is white but by clicking on one button i want to change the textcolor,textsize,etc....by changing in to this above file.
please give me idea...

Answer (score 0):

Refer : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html

You can use  setTypeface,setTextColor() etc  for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but try to use a selector for textColor inside style. how does that work out eh O_o ?